# How to fix lack of green light?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

OK, so when I went to go turn on my Xbox 360. It showed no green light but it did turn on. And it works fine but no green light!?!
So I guessed if I try to play it might still work and I went to go to sync the controller into the Xbox and I couldn't tell if it was syncing. So I tried and tried till I got a good sign. It did show the green light. But I went to go sync it and it didn't sync.
So the sync button didn't work but there was a green light. And I did get to play for an hour or so but then I got bored so hours later I went to play again and no green light showed but it did turn on.

I need to know how to get the green light fixed and the sync button on the front.

Comment: Please use better titles and grammar for your questions. Thankfully, [DJ Pirtu](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/2342/dj-pirtu) ninja'd me when editing and fixed this question up, as you can see [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/277884/revisions).

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to read. I wasn't even sure what the main question (the one to put into the title) was. Couldn't you elaborate? Also, please be spesific when talking about "green lights" if you mean the console or the controller.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your rf module may be bad or going bad....

This little chip has the leds on the power button and controlls the wireless controller functions...

A good test to verify this is if it works fine when you plug controllers in but not right otherwise....

I have had this issue with my phat 360 and it was a fairly simple job to open the console up to change this board out...and I was able to get my replacement for under $20...some people even sell these that they have had the leds replaced with special colors but as this is technically modified hardware you would void warranty and risk banishment by all mighty micromind....though I have never heard of anyone having such issue and such shuld be undetectible if done right...

Answer (score -1):

try this

this solve issue for the controller that doesn't show green light on the guide button.

Comment: Video-only answers are highly discourages. As such, please add a detailed summary of the video into your answer. If the video were to ever be taken down, the information would be lost